# Laravel from routs to controllers

Tags: веб-программирование, laravel, laravel5, backend

Как вызвать в 28 строке метод index, который находится внутри 'HomeController' ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

P.s. на запись в 28 строке выдается след. ошибка: [image: Error]

Comment: Обожаю вопросы "Вообразите мой код и ответьте".

Comment: код, пожалуйста

Comment: У вас в телеграмме непрочитанные сообщения.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Прошу простите, думал что отправил..]

Уже вопрос решен благодаря создания Route::get('/userhome', 'HomeController@index');     и в 28 строке у меня return redirect('/userhome'); Благодарю за помощь